# Jar doesn't contain my class files gitlab-ci

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When building a spring boot application in gitlab-ci, the assembled jar does not have project .class files, but have .properties file for spring.
On my PC jar contains all files and run perfectly.

e.g. gitlab-ci jar structure for BOOT-INF:

- application.properties

my pc jar structure for BOOT-INF:

- com

  - project

    - (other folders)
- application.properties

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>project</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>/src/main/server</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.project.server.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: maven:latest

cache:
   paths:
      - .m2/repository/

build:
   stage: build
   script:
      - mvn compile

test:
   stage: test
   script:
      - mvn test

deploy:
   stage: deploy
   artifacts:
      expire_in: 1 month
   paths:
      - target/*.jar
   script:
      - mvn clean package -B
      - ls target/classes/
```

Comment: Where are your java classes located? I hope in `src/main/java`+ package name? Why do you need `<sourceDirectory>/src/main/server</sourceDirectory>` ? Intentionally ?

Comment: @khmarbaise , full path to file with main function is `src\main\server\com\project\server\Main.java` . `sourceDirectory` just one of many attempts to fix issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved it. Issue is caused by non-standard path naming.

Was: `src\main\server\com\project\server\Main.java`

Changing folder `server` to `java` solves the problem

Becomes: `src\main\java\com\project\server\Main.java`